# Mostrar solo la imagen actual de perfil de usuario con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Buen día.

Alguien sabrá de casualidad como puedo mostrar solamente la imagen actual de perfil con PHP

Actualmente tengo esto así:

```
$path = "files/".$id;
if(file_exists($path)){
    $directorio = opendir($path);
    while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
        if (!is_dir($archivo)){
            echo "<div data='".$path."/".$archivo."'><a href='".$path."/".$archivo."' title='Ver Imagen'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-picture'></span></a>";
            echo "$archivo <a href='#' class='delete' title='Eliminar' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></a></div>";
            echo "<img src='files/$id/$archivo' width='300' />";
        }
    }
}
```

Pero al hacer esto se muestran todas las fotos de perfil que tiene el usuario actual, y solo quiero que me muestre la ultima que subió.

Hice estas modificaciones pero aun no queda:

```
$path = "files/".$id;
if(file_exists($path)){
    chmod($path, 0777);
    unlink($path);
    $directorio = opendir($path);
    while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
        if (!is_dir($archivo)){
            echo "<img src='files/$id/$archivo' width='200' height='200' 'image-align:center'/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Haciendo un break dentro del if después del echo obtienes una imagen. Pero debes tener alguna lógica al guardar las imágenes de perfil del usuario. Yo guardo en la base de datos la ruta de la última imagen.

Comment: En la base de datos tienes que solo guardar el nombre la imagen y dentro de tu proyecto crea una carpeta para que las almacenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, hice la prueba y tu código original funciona si la le colocas la variable `$id` con un valor. Tal vez no estés enviando el valor correcto o los directorios no se encuentren creados.

Supongo que dentro de la carpeta `files`, tenés una carpeta con cada `id` y dentro la foto de perfil. Ese es el esquema que funciona en esta lógica y si esa es la única foto la presenta sin problemas.
En el caso de que quieras cargar más fotos de ese usuario dentro de la misma carpeta, podés crear un `subdirectorio` o ponerle a todas las fotos de perfil el mismo nombre, como por ejemplo `thumbnail.png` y validar el nombre.

> **EDICIÓN**: para no validar por nombre, modifiqué la función para que
>   ordenes las imágenes modificadas y sólo muestre la última.

```
<?php
    $id = 1;
    $path = "files/".$id;
    if(file_exists($path)){
        $directorio = opendir($path);
        while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
            if (!is_dir($archivo)):
                $archivos[filemtime($path.'/'.$archivo)] = $path.'/'.$archivo;
            endif;
        }
        closedir($directorio);

        //Ordenar el array
        ksort($archivos);

        //Buscar la última modificacida
        $ultimaModificada = end($archivos);

        //Compara todas las URLs y solo muestra la última modificada
        foreach ($archivos as $archivo){
            if ($archivo == $ultimaModificada){?>
                <div data="<?php echo $path; ?>-<?php echo $archivo; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $archivo; ?>" title="Ver Imagen">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-picture'></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#"" class="delete" title="Eliminar">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <img src="<?php echo $archivo; ?>" width="300" />
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola @Lunestudio efectivamente tienes razón así esta la estructura de mi trabajo, y pues el problema es que se muestran todas las imágenes del usuario de ese id pero yo solo quiero que me muestre una, es decir que solo muestre en pantalla la ultima foto que subió o actualizo no todas. he probado tu código y funciona perfectamente pero me sigue mostrando todas las imágenes contenidas de esa carpeta, ahora estoy intentando resolver este problema con Javascript. Gracias.

Comment: Hola @Noctis, te modifiqué la respuesta para resolver este problema.

Comment: Hola @Lunestudio sirvió perfectamente te lo agradezco estimado, llevaba ya una semana en este lio y tu lo resolviste en minutos, veo que aun me falta mucho. espero te encuentres bien. Saludos.